# Subsection not showing inside header beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I want that the subsections of the current section appear at the top right of the page (where it's gray) inside my beamer document.

I thought that it was like that with the default options using the theme **Warsaw** and the color **beaver** but they are not showing up.

Here is a compilable code :

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Section 1}
\subsubsection{Subsection 1.1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsubsection{Subsection 1.2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Section 2}
\subsubsection{Subsection 2.1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsubsection{Subsection 2.2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Try use `\subsection` instead of `\subsubsection`

Comment: and never use `\section`, `\subsection` etc. inside a frame, always outside

Comment: @Sigur Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Warsaw` theme shows two horizontal bars:

- on the left, sections
- on the right, subsections

So, to print some material where you want, you have to use `\subsection{}`.

As observed by @samcarter,

> use `\section{}`, `\subsection{}`, etc... **always outside** a frame.

```
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
```

[image]